# Can I travel with my fitness tracker with me on a flight?

Tags: airports, airport-security

Can I take my fitness tracker with me on a flight? should it cause any issues while passing through security?

Comment: Short answer: yes. After all it's a portable electronic device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about a watch-style or pedometer-style fitness tracker, it should be no problem. Just take it off and put it through the X-ray, like you would with any other electronic device. In rare cases, it's possible the security agents will ask you to demonstrate that it's functioning, at which point you could show them the LCD display, but it's pretty unlikely they'll ask.

Source: personal experience. Also the TSA's ["can I bring"](https://www.tsa.gov/) feature says a Fitbit is fine.

Comment: Since I'm flying europe to the middle east, i think its safe to assume the same rules will apply here as well.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I did not even have to take it off from my wrist. (in fact I forgot to do so and was about to remove the band but was told it was okay by the security staff as I went through the body scanner)

Answer (score 1):

I took my Fitbit HR on a flight from Australia to New Zealand in January 2016 and there were no problems at all either way - since the device looks like a watch it was not questioned, and its function was unaffected by X-rays. The main thing to consider (and prepare for) is the possible loss of a bit of data due to the change in time zones.